# Match index using function only

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example I have the following three columns:

```
Column(A)        Column(B) 
NasdaqGS:SRCE    59.8%
NasdaqGS:TWOU    NA
NYSE:DDD         NA
NYSE:MMM         10%
NasdaqGS:EGHT    60%
```

How do I use Excel function only to get the following output?:

```
Column(C)
NasdaqGS:SRCE
NYSE:MMM      
NasdaqGS:EGHT
```

So I want to return tickers in column(A) that don't have an NA value in Column(B).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the list with a formula use this array formula in **C2**:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$6,MATCH(1,NOT(ISERROR($B$2:$B$6))*(COUNTIF($C$1:$C1,$A$2:$A$6)=0),0)),"")
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode. If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

---

Another method that does not require the title row or the special CSE entry:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$5,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$1:$B$5)/(NOT(ISERROR($B$1:$B$5))),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

[image]

In both formulas if the test is for the string `NA` and not the error `#N/A` then replace `NOT(ISERROR($B$2:$B$6)` with `($B$2:$B$6 <> "NA")`

Both of these are array type formulas and if the dataset and return list are large these will slow Excel's calculation times.  The method of filter, copy, un-filter, paste will be faster on large datasets.

Comment: @pnuts as I stated in the last paragraph, it would depend on how often the data changes, and how large the data set.  If a small dataset that changed often then yes this is how I would do it.  If it was a one off I would do it your way.  If it changed often and the dataset was large I would write vba to do this, most likely mimicking your advice.